# Explanation of Burmester-Desmedt group key exchange and Ingemarsson-Tang-Wong (ITW) group key exchange algorithm

Tags: key-generation, key-exchange, diffie-hellman

I know that both algorithms are similar to the Diffie-Hellman key exchange and are used for exchanging secret keys in a group but I still cannot figure out the key differences between both algorithms.
Is the difference only in the number of rounds that are required to exchange the keys?
I would appreciate an in-depth explanation.
How do both behave in case of a new member join or a member leave?

For ITW you need n-1 rounds in an n-members group. In a 3 members group, you have 2 rounds.
In the Burmester-Desmedt you always have 2 rounds, right? So in a 3 members group, there are 2 rounds anyways.
What is the difference and what will be performed in round one and two?